# yui2 update option items

Tags: javascript, yui2

I'm using yui2 framework...I have the following code....I need to add selected attribute to option node. I found this linkhttp://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23574..it deals with yui3..not quite sure about yui2.

```
`<select id="MedicationsCutOutStatus20" class="singleSelect form_input" title="Status:"name="MedicationsCutOutStatus">    
<option class="" value="All">All</option>     
<option class="" value="Active">Active</option>      
<option class="" value="On Hold">On Hold</option>      
<option class="" value="Prior History">Prior History</option>      
<option class="" value="No Longer Active">No Longer Active</option>      
</select>`

 <option selected class="" value="All">All</option>
```

I need to add selected attribute to option node..Not quite sure...how to proceed..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var selectEl = Dom.get("MedicationsCutOutStatus20");
var selectedIndex = selectEl.options.selectedIndex;
selectEl.options[selectedIndex].setAttribute("selected","");
```

If you want to select some option then you need to change selectedIndex value:

```
selectEl.options.selectedIndex = 1;
```